# Rebase a merge commit

Tags: git, rebase

Suppose my Git repository initially has two branches: Foo and Bar.

```
... ─ Foo

... ─ Bar
```

I create a third branch, FooBar in which I commit the merge of the two other branches.

```
... ─ Foo ──┐
            FooBar
... ─ Bar ──┘
```

FooBar is now one commit ahead of both Foo and Bar. Next, I do some more work, committing a few times on Foo only.

```
... ── A ───┬── B ── C ── D ── Foo
            FooBar
... ─ Bar ──┘
```

The question is: since the first parent of branch FooBar is no longer Foo, can I rebase the merge commit in branch FooBar to again have Foo and Bar as its two parents? In other words, can I incorporate the development in Foo into the previously merged FooBar along with the unchanged Bar?

```
... ── A ── B ── C ── D ── Foo ──┐
                                 FooBar
... ─ Bar ───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: See also [using git-replace to change a parent pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3811217/90527), though this has other consequences.

Comment: See also [How do I use git rebase -i after git merge without messing things up?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4152936/90527)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I realize this is quite an old topic but since I found this question while facing a similar situation I could as well tell what I used in the end.

```
git checkout FooBar
git rebase -p --onto Foo A
```

I tried to use the names from the original question. Note especially that `A` means the commit that is marked as A in the ascii art. You would probably use the hash of the commit instead or any other way to point to the commit where branches `Foo` and `FooBar` originally separate.

The `-p` flag is also known as `--preserve-merges` and it does pretty much what it says.

Note that the branch `Bar` doesn't play a role here so that line of commits might be a named branch or then not - it makes no difference.

Comment: Note that this will not keep any changes made in the merge commit.

Comment: Thanks, this helped us a lot. It's indeed important to note that 'A' is the last commit of the target branch that was still included in the original merge.

Comment: I found this answer hoping to avoid having to do the conflict resolution from the original merge commit again. As @Tgr says, it doesn't keep the original merge commit, so conflict resolution must continue as thought you just delete the merge and re-merge. It's not so bad, though, because conflicts can be resolved by checking out from the old merge commit.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement `git rerere` sounds like it might help, although I never used it myself.

Comment: Starting with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), `git --rebase-merges` (`-r`) will ultimately replace the old `git --preserve-merges` (`-p`). See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309 by VonC https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't rebase under branch `FooBar` without changing what defines `FooBar`.  What you could do  is merge `FooBar` and `Foo`.  That would have the same contents that you desire.

Comment: Yes, but the point is to avoid merge commits. That's why I want to rebase `BranchFooBar`.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused with what you want.  You say you want to avoid merge commits, but I'm interpreting your question as you wanting the final results to be a merge commit between `branchFoo` and `branchBar`.

Comment: You're right, this wasn't clear enough. I want to avoid a *2nd* merge commit. `BranchFooBar` will always be a merge commit, but I want it to be the *only* merge commit with `BranchFoo` and `BranchBar` as parents.

Comment: Checkout out `brachFooBar` and use [git revert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert) to remove the merge commit, than recreate a new merge commit with the tips of foo and bar.

Comment: `git revert` will keep the old merge commit, and will thus still result in two merge commits. In comparison with merging FooBar and Foo, `git revert` will also have an additional revert commit, which is a step in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to erase all traces of the previously made merge.

If you truly want to throw away all commits that only exists in `FooBar` (and in the working directory), then proceed as follows: first do `git checkout FooBar`, then make git forget about it's history and do `git reset --hard Foo` (if you intent to merge `Bar` into `Foo`). Then you recreate the merge with `git merge Bar`.