# Git: rebase merge commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

How i should use rebase for this case:

I have 3 features in branches:

feature/f1
feature/f2
feature/f3

and I have master branch: master
I merge this 3 features into master branch.

My commit history looks like:

Merge f3 into master
Merge f2 into master
Merge f1 into master

During testing, I found that my function f2 is not working correctly.

How could I rebase changes (not interactive mode), to my history looks like:

Merge f3 into master
Merge f1 into master

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rebase a merge commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013411/rebase-a-merge-commit)

Answer (score 6):

You could use `git rebase --preserve-merges -i HEAD~4`. This will open an editor with the three last commits. Remove the line where "Merge f2 into master" appears.

More information on [rebase -i](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: you need to add `--preserve-merges` to the rebase command, or the f3 merge won't be correctly rebased

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I need to rebase this merge commit in auto mode.
Updated description.

Comment: Is there any not-interactive mode? I need autorebase merge commit from history

Comment: @DenisB: Why don't  you want interactive mode?

Comment: I have wrote tool, that helps me to merge features into build branch.

Comment: And for rebuilding i need to rebase middle commit