# How do I squash Git commits on a branch with merges

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

I usually never do this but this time I wound up with a feature branch that, for update purposes, got master merged into it (I usually favour rebase master on my feature branch to avoid useless merge commits).

And now I want to squash all commits of my feature branch into one before merging it as finalised to master but it is not as seamless as it usually is.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248231/git-rebase-after-previous-git-merge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interactive rebase after merging/other commits interleaving mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826197/interactive-rebase-after-merging-other-commits-interleaving-mine)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174055/git-rebase-after-merge

Comment: Do you want to preserve the merge commit with `master`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git rebase after previous git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248231/git-rebase-after-previous-git-merge)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to merge all the changes as single commit using `merge --squash`

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature_branch
git commit -a
```

Note: However, this doesn't really do a merge. It is more akin to doing a single commit on master itself. That's why I always mention the name of the merged branch explicitly in commit message.