# git reword without resolving merge conflicts again

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

Is it possible to change commit messages using git rebase, but without having to re-resolve merge conflicts?

I need to bowdlerize an older repo and I don't want to change any of the actual code, just the messages.

I've tried `--preserve-merges`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a little-known feature of git called "Reuse Recorded Resolutions", or `rerere`.

You can enable it globally by running `git config --global rerere.enabled true`.

If `rerere` is enabled, `git` will automatically save conflict resolutions, and will reuse those resolutions later if it encounters the same conflicts. This has the net result of not requiring the user to re-resolve these previously seen conflicts.

The feature is explained here - [Git - Rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere).

The documentation for `git rerere` command is here - [git-rerere(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this will only help you if you had it enabled when you first did the merges - by now it's too late. There is [a script called rerere-train](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/contrib/rerere-train.sh) in the contrib portion of Git's source which goes through existing history and makes rerere learn conflict resolutions from existing merges - assuming it works, that'd help you in this case.

Answer (score 12):

Note: since The [`contrib/rerere-train.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ad53bf79aa4ea20a8a94af9e2df5a8311ca1e55e/contrib/rerere-train.sh) script is supposed to re-train rerere (you can see a [manual retraining here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155237/6309))

To make sure `rerere` forgets all its current rebase resolution, you now have an official option with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017) for `contrib/rerere-train`: the `--overwrite` flag.

See [commit ad53bf7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad53bf79aa4ea20a8a94af9e2df5a8311ca1e55e) (26 Jul 2017) by [Raman Gupta (`rocketraman`)](https://github.com/rocketraman).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aec68c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aec68c3dde55601796ceee5f97cc362d58a9bd54), 11 Aug 2017)</sup>

> `contrib/rerere-train`: optionally overwrite existing resolutions
>
> Provide the user an option to overwrite existing resolutions using an
>   `--overwrite` flag.
>
> This might be used, for example, if the user knows that they already have an entry in their rerere cache for a conflict, but wish to drop it and retrain based on the merge commit(s) passed to the rerere-train script.

Comment: How do we call rerere-train? 
Should we create a new file and then run the scripts?

Comment: @omg you can can see example of calling [that script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/rerere-train.sh) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42416725/6309

Comment: Does this work for cherry-picks too? It doesn't seem like it would by looking at the linked source code (it seems to skip non-merges entirely).

Comment: @Vegard I have not tested it but I doubt it would work for cherry-picking indeed.