# How to get a rebase from a git branch that has done numerous git merge and pulls

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I want to be able to get a clean rebase on a branch someone else has worked on using a merge resolve conflict strategy.

1. What's the easiest way to accomplish that?
2. Can I reuse their previous conflict resolutions along the way?

Answer (score 1):

You might still need to resolve conflicts, but I would look into [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) that I mentioned in "[Are there any downsides to enabling git rerere?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519698/6309)".

You can [activate rerere and train it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664714/6309), in order for git to record past conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this (assuming `main` is the branch to rebase on top of) would be

```bash
git branch someone_elses_branch.rebased someone_elses_branch
git rebase main someone_elses_branch.rebased
```

This will have git attempting to apply the commits from `someone_elses_branch.rebased` on top of `main` and if there is a significant amount of changes between the common merge base and the top of `main` you might end up with conflicts due to the aggregate of them being applied at once, while if you had rebased the branch just one commit at a time you could have avoided some of them.

Therefore you could try out using [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) instead which basically does that, rebasing incrementally along all commits on a branch.