# GIT rebase on a merged branch creates conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I am working on my branch which I keep merging with the master which works well. But the problem arrives when my pre-checkin pipeline starts by taking my SHA and tries to apply latest SHA from master via rebasing method. This always ends in conflict. This process of rebasing in pre-checkin cannot be changed. Anyway during rebasing conflicts can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on my branch which I keep merging with the master which works well.

Ideally, you might want to keep *rebasing* your branch on top of `master`, possibly with [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) active, in order to memorize past conflict resolution (see "[Are there any downsides to enabling `git rerere`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519698/6309)")

That way, when your pre-checkin step does its rebase, that automatic step which cannot be avoided becomes trivial.

Comment: But there are many developers who will need to enable the rerere feature on their local. Anything can be done while doing a rebasing?

Comment: @Hacker While rebasing: [train your git rerere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664714/6309). But yes, rerere is a local setting.