# Can I force a "no-changes rebase" without a rerere history DB?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-filter-repo

I have a git repository in which there have been a bunch of merge conflicts, especially due to CRLF vs LF issues (ugh). Anyway, I want to change a commit message on some past commit, and otherwise keep everything as-is in the code. I neither have `rerere.enabled`, nor do I have a historical database, nor do I want to have one. I just want to tell git-rebase to "Keep everything just the same", except for a commit comment which is pure meta-data.

Can I do this?

Related questions:

- [git reword shows merge conflict during rebase, however pick works correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56264030/1593077) 
  (in which `-r` is specified; and the answer suggests using `rerere`)
- [Smarter rebase avoiding redundant work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601541/smarter-rebase-avoiding-redundant-work)

Comment: So, what is different in your situation from the first one you linked to? And why does the answer to that question, including the links to a description of the rerere-train.sh script, not also answer your question?

Comment: @IMSoP: 1. The first one uses `-r`. Maybe I should mention that.  2. I explicitly said I want to _not_ use rerere nor train anything, just preserve what already exists.

Comment: I would use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) for this task.

Comment: @j6t: That sounds like it could make an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry, I don't follow. If you want to rebase merges, then you need "-r" (or some variation of it) regardless of whether there were conflicts; if you *don't* need to rebase merges, then there aren't any merge conflicts to worry about. And you haven't said **why** you don't want to use "rerere"; you don't have to use it ever again, but it's a tool which can do this job. The linked answer even goes into great detail about why there's no such thing as a "no-changes rebase" under the hood, because rebase has to recreate every commit even if it's *not* changed.

Comment: @IMSoP: I don't want to use rerere because it's not the right tool. I don't want git to user some database which may-or-may-not-have been gathered correctly, I want it to maintain everything as is and not risk changes to the code. Also, recreating commits is just fine - I want that to happen. But there aren't, nor can there be, any unresolved conflicts in this recreation when the only change I've made is to meta-data.

Comment: With git-filter-repo, depending on which kind of editing of the commit message you want to do, you can get away with `--replace-message <expressions_file>`, or you have to write a full `--message-callback <function_body>`. The latter requires some Python skills.

Comment: You *don't* want to use `git rebase` (with or without `-r`) here as this *could* produce the wrong result even if you did have rerere enabled and/or trained here. The reason is that rerere only applies to actual conflicts, and it's possible that someone deliberately made some sort of non-conflicting changes during merges (by running `git merge -n` and then editing and adding files). So you really *do* want a tool like filter-branch or filter-repo here.

Comment: @torek: It's very strange to me that git rebase would insist on messing up the commit DAG for merely changing a commit message.

Comment: With `-r`, you'd have a fine *DAG* copy (without `-r`, rebase will flatten the graph). The issue isn't the copying of the commit subgraph. It's the copying of the *contents*. A merge made with `-n` and then additional changes—also known as an [*evil merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)—will lose these changes when the merge is re-performed without re-doing the evil step.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(a variation on on @j6t 's suggestion:)</sub>

You can use the commit editing feature of [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo). This tool is generally interesting for applying callback-based or  analysis-based transformations on git repositories, but the specific capability you would likely use is the ability to run a given Python script on each commit:

```
$ cd /path/to/repository
$ git-filter-repo --commit-callback 'SCRIPT BODY HERE'
```

Now, when the script is run, an object named `commit` will be defined. This object has, among others, the fields `commit.original_id` holding the hash, and `commit.message` holding the commit message. Thus your script might be something like:

```
'if (commit.hash.startswith(b"0xdeadbeaf")):
    commit.message.replace(b"Hello world", b"Goodbye world")
'
```

You can also look at [a few more examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES) of git-filter-repo scripts.

Caveat: Haven't tried this myself yet.