# Update previous merge commit without resolving conflicts twice

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a repo with two branches, `main` and `feature`. The output of `git log --graph --format='%s %d' --all` looks like the following:

```
* e  (main)
| * d  (HEAD -> feature)
| *   Merge branch 'main' into feature 
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | c 
| * b 
|/  
* a
```

I now want to include the commit `e` on my `main` branch in the merge commit on the `feature` branch, so that I have the latest changes on `main`, but don't have to force push if commit `b` on the `feature` branch is already pushed. I also don't want to have another merge commit in my history. I want my final graph to look like this:

```
| * d  (HEAD -> feature)
| *   Merge branch 'main' into feature 
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | e  (main)
* | c 
| * b 
|/  
* a
```

I can achieve that with `git rebase -i main --onto :/a --rebase-merges` and change the instructions for the interactive rebase to:

```
label onto

reset 9870d06 # a
pick 579c27a b
merge -C d4caa73 main # Merge branch 'main' into feature
pick f672b7f d
```

The problem with that though is that in the previous merge commit, I had to resolve a conflict between `b` and `c`, and with this approach, I would have to resolve this conflict again. Therefore, what I would really like to do is pick up the merge commit where I left off at commit `c` on `main` and just continue with merging `e` into `feature` on top of `b`. Is there a way to achieve this? Perhaps there is also a way to introduce another merge commit temporarily and then squash these two merge commits afterwards?

Comment: Could you show what you expect in the end using the `git log` format please? Reasoning on a git graph is easier, at least for me.

Comment: I have added that now, hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git *does* include something designed for this kind of work-flow.  There's a hitch: you must turn it on *before* you do your first merge.

Fortunately, there's a third-party solution to the hitch, called `git rerere-train`, which is included with Git distributions now (but still not installed directly).  See, e.g., the accepted answer to [Smarter rebase avoiding redundant work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10601541/1256452)

While this question (from eight years ago!) is about rebase, the same concept works with the `git merge` performed by `--rebase-merges`.  In fact, the conflicts that occur during rebase *are* merge conflicts.  You don't need the full training the script can do; you could use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155237/1256452) (from *ten* years ago!) to teach Git the resolutions you used earlier.

Do note that once you turn on `rerere.enabled`, Git will keep checking for previous resolutions and re-using them, even if you *don't* want that to happen (e.g., if you realize you resolved something incorrectly and want to do it over again).  You can turn it off with the same kind of `git config` operation you used to turn it on, though.  Note also that even with the *re*-use *re*coreded *re*solutions (rerere) option turned on, Git will stop after a conflicted merge that does take these recorded resolutions.  This gives you an opportunity to check the result.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!