# git rebase interractive before merge with conflict

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-merge-conflict

I am trying to modify commits from before a merge where I had to solve conflicts (especially, I want to squash a new commit into one before the merge, but just rewriting commit messages lead to the same issue).

When I use:

```
git rebase -i --rebase-merges SHA~1
```

I have to resolve the conflicts of the merge again, this is really time consuming and I don't understand why the conflicts appear again.

Is there a way to modify commits before a merge with conflicts without having to resolve the conflicts again ?

Answer (score 1):

A regular rebase copies commits as if with (or sometimes literally with) `git cherry-pick`, and each cherry-pick operation *is* a merge.  A `--rebase-merges` rebase copies merges by re-performing the merges on the new copies of the old commits made with the earlier cherry-pick steps.  So if there are 47 original commits to copy, 3 of them being merges, you'll have 44 opportunities for `git cherry-pick` to produce merge conflicts, and 3 more for `git merge` to produce conflicts.

If you had conflicts before, it's very likely you will have the *same ones* again.  Here, `git rerere` can be quite helpful.  There is talk of turning it on by default in future Git releases.  Until then, since you already have some merges, consider using `rerere-train`: see [Smarter rebase avoiding redundant work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10601541/1256452)  See also [What is git-rerere and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49500943/1256452)