# Resolve conflicts many times after 'git rebase'

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have my git with commit history like:

```
master    A--B
feature    \C--D
```

I wanted to merge `feature` branch into `master`, so I intended to **rebase** `feature` branch in order to have a clean commit history, and then make a merge request into the `master`.

But when I ran `git rebase master`, git required to resolve conflicts between `C` and `B`, then `git add`, then resolve between `D` and `C`, and `git add` again, which is exhausted. After that, the `git log` at local feature looked like `A--B--C--D`, which was what I wanted to be.

At that moment, I realized the local log was different from the remote counterpart, so I had to do `git pull` again, then resolve conflicts although the code looked the same.

Did I do something incorrect? Any suggestions about a standard, efficient way to merge a `feature` branch into the `master` branch?

Comment: Could you also share the difference between your remote and local git history?

Comment: After applying multiple modification, I messed it up so I deleted the branch. Do you have any suggestions about a delicate way to merge a branch into master?

Answer (score 0):

> then resolve conflicts although the code looked the same.

That is why in your scenario, it is interesting to activate [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere), with [`git config rerere.enabled`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-rerereenabled).

Use, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155237/6309), [`rerere-train.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89bece5c8c96f0b962cfc89e63f82d603fd60bed/contrib/rerere-train.sh) in order to benefit from past resolution.